# Importing an existing python module into new eclipse pydev project

Tags: eclipse, pydev

In eclipse, when I create a new pydev project and import an existing python module into that project, I lose all syntax and variable coloring (all pale black text). If I just open the python module under no project, everything is fine, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I solved it. It seems when you use pyuic4 to convert .ui to .py, it encodes it to utf2, at least in python 3.7.1. I converted the file to utf8 coding and everything worked. If anyone can add to this I would greatly appreciate it.